# Does ID2D1DeviceContext::GetTarget() create a new pointer via AddRef()

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, com, atl, direct2d

I am wandering if I should use a CComPtr ccptr_d2d_image whenever I call GetTarget(). For example:

```
void DrawSomething (ID2D1DeviceContext *dvctxt, ID2D1Bitmap1 *arg_bitmap1)
{

CComPtr<ID2D1Image> ccptr_d2d_image = NULL;

// save the current target
dvctxt->GetTarget(&ccptr_d2d_image);

dvctxt->BeginDraw();
dvctxt->Flush(); // clear any previous errors on the tgt
dvctxt->SetTarget(arg_bitmap1);

// draw something on the arg_bitmap1

dvctxt->EndDraw();

// restore the previous target
dvctxt->BeginDraw();
dvctxt->Flush();     // clear any previous errors on the tgt
dvctxt->SetTarget(ccptr_d2d_image);
dvctxt->EndDraw();

} // Com Pointer goes out of scope and is automatically released
```

Comment: Your code is fine as is. GetTarget implementation will internally increment reference count in some way (AddRef, QueryInterface, etc.) and give the pointer back in your ccptr_d2d_image variable and when CComPtr goes out of scope, it calls Release. You're in the exact same situation as in the official doc example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class#remarks